# Let $G$ be a group then does $\{e\}/G$ make sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

For context,

I was trying to show that the quotient of a solvable group is solvable.

For a normal subgroup $N$ I was able to show that ${(G/N)}^{(k)}={G}^{(k)}/N$ and thus by using the fact that $G$ is solvable so ${G}^{(k)}=\{e\}$ for some $k\ge0$ I was trying to show that ${(G/N)}^{(k)}={G}^{(k)}/N=\{N\}$ and then got stuck thinking if $\{e\}/G$ even made any sense.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, $\{e\}/G$ does not make sense unless $G=\{e\}$.

Comment: Your equation is incorrect. What you *may* have been able to show is that $(G/N)^{(k)}=(G^{(k)}N)/N$, which would actually make sense, whereas what you wrote is incorrect whenever $G^{(k)}$ does not contain $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use $G^{(k)}/N$. What is the identity element of that quotient?

> You need to show $(G/N)^{(k)}=\{N\}$. What's the homomorphic image of the quotient map, $\phi:G\rightarrow G/N$ for $G^{(k)}$? (Hint: Identity map to identity)

Comment: It must be $\{N\}$. That was clear from the theorem which states that the homomorphic image of a solvable group is solvable but I was trying to use the same steps of the theorem but without involving homomorphism to show $G/N$ is solvable. Even without that context does $\{e\}/G$ make any sense?

Comment: No, think quotient like $\text{big_area}/\text{tile}$. This split the area into small chunks. Now, what if the area is empty? Does the tiling make sense? When the tiling only make sense?  @Al-AminMiah

Comment: The tiling will only make sense if we can fit tiles without breaking any of them in the given area, i.e., the big_area is divisible by the area of the tile. It's clear now, thanks.